# How to check place value of each digit in prolog?

Tags: prolog, numbers

```
toword(0,'zero').
toword(1,'one').
toword(10,'ten').
toword(15,'fifteen').
toword(30,'thirty').
toword(100,'one hundred').
toword(500,'five hundred').
toword(2000,'two thousand).

pv(X,[]).
//pv(X , [H|T) :- toword(X/10, T), pv(???  I know this is wrong.
```

I am trying to get each place value and put it into a list. For example; X = 2531 the list would be [two thousand, five hundred, thirty, one]. I didn't put all of the toword() facts, but there would be more. I don't know how I am supposed to get each place value of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Converting an integer into its English language spoken form is rather a more difficult problem than you might think.

You first thing you need to do is partition your value into a list of 3-digit groups (the proper name for which is *period*):

```
groups( 0 , Gs , Gs ) .
groups( N , Ts , Gs ) :- N > 0, div_rem(N,1000,Q,R), groups(Q,[R|Ts],Gs).

div_rem(X,Y,Q,R) :-
    Q is X div Y,
    R is X rem Y.
```

That will turn an integer like `1234567890` into

```
[ 1, 234, 567, 890 ]
```

Something like this will give you the correct suffix based on the groups position with respect to the right of the list:

```
period( 2, thousand    ).
period( 3, million     ).
period( 4, billion     ).
period( 5, trillion    ).
period( 6, quadrillion ).
period( 7, quintillion ).
period( 8, sextillion  ).
```

The only real tricky bit is figuring out how to handle the 1st/rightmost such *period* (hundreds). The numbers from 0-99 are problematic:

- The values 0-19 are an irregular formation,
- The values 20-99 are absolutely regular, and formed by taking the name of the *decade* (`twenty`, `thirty`, etc.), appending a `-` and then appending the name of the digit in the ones place.

These are the special numbers:

```
special(  0, zero       ).
special(  1, one        ).
special(  2, two        ).
special(  3, three      ).
special(  4, four       ).
special(  5, five       ).
special(  6, six        ).
special(  7, seven      ).
special(  8, eight      ).
special(  9, nine       ).
special( 10, ten        ).
special( 11, eleven     ).
special( 12, twelve     ).
special( 13, thirteen   ).
special( 14, fourteeen  ).
special( 15, fifteen    ).
special( 16, sixteen    ).
special( 17, seventeen  ). 
special( 18, eighteen   ).
special( 19, nineteen   ).
special( 20, twenty     ).
special( 30, thirty     ).
special( 40, forty      ).
special( 50, fifty      ).
special( 60, sixty      ).
special( 70, seventy    ).
special( 80, eighty     ).
special( 90, ninety     ).
```

Here's how to construct the names of any number from 0-999:

```
group_name( 0 , Ws , Ws ) :- !.
group_name( N , Ws , W1 ) :-
    div_rem(N,100,Q,R),
    hundreds(Q,Ws,W0),
    tens_and_ones(R,W0,W1).
                 
hundreds( 0 , Ws              , Ws ).
hundreds( N ,  [W,hundred|W0] , W0 ) :- N > 0, special(N,W).

tens_and_ones( N ,     [W|Ws] , Ws ) :- special(N,W), !.
tens_and_ones( N , [W1-W2|Ws] , Ws ) :-
    Ones is N rem 10,
    Tens is N - Ones,
    special(Tens,W1),
    special(Ones,W2).
```

Once you have that, everything else is easy. It's just a matter of tracking which period you're currently processing and appending the correct suffix

```
int_words( N , _             ) :- \+ integer(N), !, fail.
int_words( N , [negative|Ws] ) :- N <  0, X is abs(N), number_phrase(X,Ws).
int_words( N ,           Ws  ) :- N >= 0,              number_phrase(N,Ws).

number_phrase(N,Ws) :-
    groups(N,[],Gs),
    length(Gs,P),
    groups_to_words(Gs,P,Ws).

groups_to_words( [G]    , _ , Ws ) :-
    group_name(G,Ws,[]).
groups_to_words( [G|Gs] , P , Ws ) :-
    period(P,Sfx),
    group_name(G,Ws,[Sfx|W1]),
    P1 is P-1,
    groups_to_words(Gs,P1,W1).
```

You can fiddle with it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/int-words.pl

Answer (score 0):

```
toword(0, 'zero').
toword(1, 'one').
toword(10, 'ten').
toword(15, 'fifteen').
toword(30, 'thirty').
toword(100, 'one hundred').
toword(500, 'five hundred').
toword(2000, 'two thousand').

to_words(N, Lst) :-
    to_words_(N, Lst).

to_words_(N, Lst) :-
    % Using compare, to prevent unwanted choicepoint
    compare(Comp, N, 0),
    to_words_comp_(Comp, N, Lst).

to_words_comp_(=, 0, []).
to_words_comp_(>, N, [Text|Lst]) :-
    toword_min(N, TextN, Text),
    N0 is N - TextN,
    % Loop until zero is reached
    to_words_(N0, Lst).

toword_min(N, TextN, Text) :-
    toword(TextN, Text),
    TextN =< N,
    % Ensure this is the most fitting number to use
    \+ (toword(TextNOther, _), TextNOther =< N, TextNOther > TextN),
    % No need to search for multiple answers
    !.
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(to_words(2531, Lst)).
% 286 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 1656013 Lips)
Lst = ['two thousand','five hundred',thirty,one].
```

Comment: Would there be a simpler way to solve this problem? Without using compare?

Comment: Simpler, yes (I leave that as an exercise for you - it's a trivial modification to the above code). However, taking advantage of first-argument indexing, to prevent unwanted choicepoints whilst still keeping the potential for "generality", is a better coding style.